# How to show the results of a Haystack Query on a separate page

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have a index.html where my form is implemented:

```
...
{% block searchform%} {% endblock %}
...
```

In my search/ folder I have two files.

search.html, which is the actual form for the index.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block searchform %}
    <form method="get" action="/results/">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

and the file result.html, where I want to see my search results:

```
{% if query %}
<h3>Results</h3>
...
{% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from dev_devices.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^results/$', results, name = 'results')
)
```

view.py

```
def results(request):
    return render_to_response('results.html')
```

My problem is, that there are no results showing up. When I click on the submit Button of my form, I will redirected to the correct file (results.html), but no results are showing up.

The example of the installation guide of haystack (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation) worked fine. But this example is only showing the way, if the form and the result page is the same page.

Comment: You should be able to piece together how this works if you have ever done a post request to your django app. The view that you want to use needs to do the actual search and then pass the results on to the template.

Comment: you are not sending a querset, or the context into `results.html` from the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
def results(request):
    return render_to_response('results.html')
```

Do you see some results here? I don`t...